# Linux Shell - Display system information in upper part of the screen

Tags: linux, shell

out of curiosity:
Is there a way to display system information in the upper third of a linux shell that stays there and updates automatically?

In my humble understanding this would maybe require something like a curses program which displays two windows, the upper containing the respective information and the lower displaying a regular shell.

I didn't find anything alike which is why I'm asking here.
If nothing alike already exists I am (like any good linux user should be :D) motivated to write my own, but yeah, maybe there's no need to reinvent the wheel...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It certainly exists in [byobu](http://byobu.co/) (at the **bottom** of the screen, hope you do not mind, ;-)), which works both in a graphical environment and in a normal tty. `byobu` is an enhancement of a normal terminal which you might find quite useful.

In a graphical environment there are desktop-specific applets that do that, for Gnome, KDE, Xfce, ... whatever.

Comment: Cool! I would be converted if I didn't have to maintain AIX too.

Comment: Whoa there, that is one mighty tool, thanks for the suggestion, I think I'm going to try it out!

Answer (score 3):

IMHO while there are tons of indicator utilities, and the quicker a terminal/shell responds the better, it's not a good idea to put the load of checking and displaying status infos onto their shoulders.

But you can, and pretty easily. Just look for the **screen** program. With it, you can split your window to two (or more) parts, and you can increase or decrease the heights of those parts. You can run any status displaying program/script above and do your job below.

I think, the introduction of screen is over this place, but I can give you the kez you should look for in the manual of the progam: "Split the current region vertically", Enter command line mode", "increase current region height", "Switch the input focus to  the  next  region", "Toggle  to  the  window displayed previously", "Create a new window with a shell"

Not little to read but much less than to read for developing it from scratch.

Comment: Sounds interesting and definitely more lightweight than `byobu`, I will give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: @MäxMüller I think you may be mistaken: `byobu` is a 6.7KB program,  and is never seen on `top`.  It is **very** lightweight, not being graphical and all.

Comment: That was wrong wording on my side, what I actually meant was, that the functional range of `byobu` may be too much for my needs and that the `screen` solution may suffice...